# Make new dlg windows mouse position or somewhere specific

Tags: photoshop-script

I'm a beginner, I'm trying to match the new created dlg windows to match the position of my mouse or at least somewhere specific, can anyone help?

var dlg = new Window("dialog",[100,495,300,540]);
Tried but look like this is not working.

Comment: var dlg = new Window("dialog","",["","250","450","450"]);

If I use this, all the button, panel in the windows will disappear but position of the windows changed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are after a window that's 220 x 45 then I think you want:

```
var dialog = new Window("dialog"); 
    dialog.text = "Dialog"; 
    dialog.preferredSize.width = 200; 
    dialog.preferredSize.height = 45; 
dialog.show();
```

Position the window - I'm not so sure about that. A few versions ago any dialog or windows were default to the top left. And you had to use `var win = new Window(dlg,'My dialog window'); win.center();` to put them in the centre. It may be possible to position them at exact coordinates.

However...

Two things that will make your life much easier is the [Photoshop scriptUI guide](https://indd.adobe.com/view/a0207571-ff5b-4bbf-a540-07079bd21d75)
and [Joonas Pääkkö's ScriptUI Dialog Builder](https://scriptui.joonas.me/). The latter will do a lot of the heavy lifting for you. You're welcome.